# Can't focus on a <td> element in my table on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a table and when I click on a button I want to set the contenteditable to true, which I do, and then put focus on the td element so the client sees a cursor blinking in the cell.

I can't seem to get the focus to work on the LicenseName cell. I know the 'tableData' variable contains the correct element, I've checked it in the browser debugger.

Here is what I've tried.

```js
editLicensesDetails = function (e) {
        var tableRow = $(e.target).parent().parent();
        $(tableRow).css('background-color', '#dff0d8');
        $(tableRow).children('[contenteditable]').attr("contenteditable", "true");
        var tableData = $(tableRow).children('[contenteditable]')[0];
        $(tableData).focus();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table id="tableLicenseDetails" style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Unit Of Measure</th>
                        <th>Variable Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                            <td style="display:none;">@license.LicenseId</td>
                            <td>
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td contenteditable="false">@license.LicenseName</td>
                            <td contenteditable="false">@license.LicenseDescription</td>
                            <td>@license.TradePulseProductName</td>
                            <td>@license.LicenseUnitOfMeasureTypeName</td>
                            <td>@license.IsVariableRate</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly. That means something is wrong when you calling the editLicensesDetails function

```js
  var tableRow = $('tr');
  $(tableRow).css('background-color', '#dff0d8');
  $(tableRow).children('[contenteditable]').attr("contenteditable", "true");
  var tableData = $(tableRow).children('[contenteditable]')[0];
  $(tableData).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="false">LicenseName</td>
    <td contenteditable="false">LicenseDescription</td>
   
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know I'm getting the correct data in the editLicenseDetails function and in the variable 'tableData' I have the correct element (<td>). What else can I look at?

Comment: @Tushar Gupta: Your snippet works for me using Google Chrome, but the tds are neither editable nor gain focus with Internet Explorer.